# relationship between tantra and devotion

Tags: tantra, bhakti

I'm not really asking for the differences but I also believe that devotion as Lord Krishna mentions in Geeta is the best path for enlightnment.

I'm just curious if there is any relationship between the tantric principles/practises and devotion.

Comment: without bhakti there is not tantra, look at the life work of sri ramakrishna . He was a sakta tantrik.

Comment: so, the most profound tantriks are also bhaktas, but bhaktas may not be tantriks?

Comment: also look at the work of krishnanda agambagis, who said love bhakti and compassion is the greatest mantra

Comment: It seems that you are looking at tantrism as an engineered system ,disconnected. Tantrism can only been seen as an evolution of bhakti. They are just dependent on each other, everything starts in our heart , not in our mind.